# Memory overflow exception when creating bitmaps in a loop

Tags: c#, memory, bitmap, overflow, imaging

I have to import a large amount of image crops off of many images that are all ready stored in my database. I have tried using statements and disposing of my bitmap objects each time. But I am still getting a Memory Overflow Exception that my system is out of memory.

Here is some sample code of what I am doing.

```
public void CropImage(List<ImageClass> data)
{
    foreach (var obj in data)
    {
        //I have a data base method that returns a data object that 
        //contains the file bytes of the image id in data: 'file'
        //My List<ImageClass> data contains an ID of the original image
        //start x,y coords for the upper left corner of the rectangle,
        //and the width and height of the rectangle.

        Image img = Image.FromStream(new MemoryStream(file.Data));
        Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap((Bitmap)img);
        Rectangle cropArea = new Rectangle(obj.x_coordinate,
                                           obj.y_coordinate,
                                           obj.width,
                                           obj.height);

        Bitmap cropImage = bmp.Clone(cropArea, bmp.PixelFormat);

        SaveFile(cropImage, file, obj.scanID);

        img.Dispose();
        bmp.Dispose();
        cropImage.Dispose();
    }
}


    public void SaveFile(Bitmap cropImage, FileData file, int OCRscanID)
    {
        EncoderParameters encoderParams = new EncoderParameters();
        encoderParams.Param[0] = new EncoderParameter(
                                          System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder.Quality,
                                          50L);

        ImageCodecInfo codecInfo = GetEncoderInfo("image/jpeg");
        MemoryStream newImage = new MemoryStream();
        cropImage.Save(newImage, codecInfo, encoderParams);

        byte[] newData = newImage.ToArray();

        //Saving data bytes to database of the cropped image 
    }

    private ImageCodecInfo GetEncoderInfo(string mimeType)
    {
        int j;
        ImageCodecInfo[] encoders;
        encoders = ImageCodecInfo.GetImageEncoders();
        for (j = 0; j < encoders.Length; ++j)
        {
            if (encoders[j].MimeType == mimeType)
                return encoders[j];
        }
        return null;
    }
```

I know I can trim up some of the code like searching for an encoder to just use the image/jpeg. But i had another application for this code another project. I just can't seem to get past the memory overflow.

I need to cycle through about 20k images.

Comment: Wait.. you aren't keeping the bitmap images as binary on SQL server, do you?

Comment: have you tried a profiling tool, such as memprofiler?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're not disposing your memory streams.  Everything that implements `IDisposable` should be disposed.

[Is a memory leak created if a MemoryStream in .NET is not closed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/234059/is-a-memory-leak-created-if-a-memorystream-in-net-is-not-closed)

Comment: this is true, but won't cause a leak as implemented.  Obviously you should still call dispose and not rely on the implementation details of MemoryStream.

Comment: @Yaur, you're probably right. But, when something isn't working, start by eliminating everything that is wrong, no matter how trivial, until you find the real cause.

Comment: This was really it. I was having 2 memory streams opened. Big mistake when dealing with this much data. Also I was just bringing in a new memory stream and never defining it...or disposing of it. I created a VERY stripped down version that works and no memory leak. Processes cropping of each image in about .27 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

[Ants memory profiler](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-memory-profiler/) is an invaluable tool for debugging these types of problems.  At first glance the only problem I see is that you have a leak if you ever throw an exception.

what I would do is to use `using` instead of manually disposing your objects and make sure you are logging exceptions.  If that doesn't do it and the memory profiler doesn't show you any problems try adding a `GC.collect()` as this may help if your large object heap is getting fragmented, which is relatively likely with this sort of code.

Answer (score 0):

There are a certain number of options available to you which can be helpful like
bitmap compress , bitmap recycle , bitmap scaling , catching bitmaps.

### Catching Bitmaps

[Catching OutOfMemoryError in decoding Bitmap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7138645/catching-outofmemoryerror-in-decoding-bitmap)

### Recycle bitmaps

[Android: Bitmap recycle() how does it work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3823799/android-bitmap-recycle-how-does-it-work)

### Bitmap compress

[How to make Bitmap compress without change the bitmap size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8417034/how-to-make-bitmap-compress-without-change-the-bitmap-size)

### Bitmap scaling

[Android - Scale and compress a bitmap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20599834/android-scale-and-compress-a-bitmap)