# Bitmap compress doesn't changing bitmap byte size

Tags: android, bitmap

I'm trying to reduce bitmap size by using compress method.

This is my code:

```
public Bitmap compressImage(Bitmap image) {
        Bitmap immagex = image;
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        Log.i("before compress", immagex.getByteCount()+"");

        boolean compress = immagex.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 10, baos);

        if(compress)
            Log.i("after compress", immagex.getByteCount()+"");
        else
            Log.i("bad compress", "bad compress");

        return immagex;
    }
```

When i check my logs i get:

```
11-28 11:10:38.252: I/before compress(2429): 374544
11-28 11:10:38.262: I/after compress(2429): 374544
```

Why is the compress does not work?

**UPDATE:**

I tried this code:

```
public Bitmap compressImage(Bitmap image) {
        Bitmap immagex = image;
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        Log.i("before compress", immagex.getByteCount()+"");

        boolean compress = immagex.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 10, baos);

        Log.i("after compress 2", decodeSampledBitmapFromByte(image.getWidth(), image.getHeight(), baos.toByteArray()).getByteCount()+"");

        return immagex;
    }
```

Still the same byte count

```
11-28 11:33:04.335: I/before compress(3472): 374544
11-28 11:33:04.395: I/after compress 2(3472): 374544
```

Comment: please refer follwing link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8417034/how-to-make-bitmap-compress-without-change-the-bitmap-size

Comment: Its not my issue.
I dont want to scale my bitmap just to reduce is size in memory by changing is quilaty.

Comment: Was a solution found for this problem? I'm facing the very same issue here.

Comment: I am facing same issue. Actually my byte array is increasing with lower compression param

Answer (score 3):

Following is the code for reducing the bitmap size and convert it to base64,

```
    Bitmap newBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, 50, 50, true);
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    newBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
    byte[] byteArray = baos.toByteArray();
    String imageEncoded = Base64.encodeToString(byteArray, Base64.DEFAULT);

    Log.e("Base 64 String", imageEncoded);
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment but i already tried other solution that dont use changing size...

Comment: this didn't work for me either. Is this an Android bug?

Answer (score 0):

Using Bitmap.compress() you just specify compression algorithm and by the way compression operation takes rather big amount of time. If you need to play with sizes for reducing memory allocation for your image, you exactly need to use scaling of your image using Bitmap.Options, computing bitmap bounds at first and then decoding it to your specified size.

The best sample that I found on StackOverflow is this one.
[Strange out of memory issue while loading an image to a Bitmap object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/477572/strange-out-of-memory-issue-while-loading-an-image-to-a-bitmap-object/823966#823966)

Comment: I dont want to scale the bitmap just to reduce is quality.

Answer (score 0):

Compression does not change the size of the bitmap. You should look at the size of the output byte stream which contains compressed data.