# Decode large image file into small fixed size

Tags: android

I am new to Android application development.

I have large image file set into small fixed size ImageView but it is not display properly. It appears blurred and not clearly visible. Below is my code.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where is the code ???

Comment: I have try all the cases, which is in my code ...

Comment: I want to draw signature in full screen and set into fixed size image on save but image view not show properly, I think problem is that large bitmap  set into small image view , Please help me..

Answer (score 0):

You can resize image bitmap using below code.

```
Bitmap <Your image bitmap>;
int height = (bitmap.getHeight() * 512 / bitmap.getWidth());
Bitmap scale = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, 512,height, true);
iv_signature.setImageBitmap(scale);
```

And also set `android:scaleType="fitXY"` in layout xml file for display complete image.

Comment: This is my image view, <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/iv_signature"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="150dp"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tx_signatural"
                    android:background="@drawable/image"
                    android:padding="2dp"/>

Comment: No i have get the drawing catch of the layout, save into file and decode this file into bitmap and set into image view.

Comment: Can you post image of your problem regarding to ImageView?

Comment: This is my original bitmap screen short- http://i.imgur.com/MIja7lF.png, on save set this bitmap as it is on this image view please see this screen short- http://i.imgur.com/giPUp45.png

Comment: For that you have to see this answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8417034/how-to-make-bitmap-compress-without-change-the-bitmap-size/8419112#8419112