# how to compress bitmap in volley android

Tags: android, android-volley

i wanted to know that how to compress the size of bitmap in volley

when i try to compress then then the image will not displaying

i have try this

```
  mImageLoader.get(imageUrl, new ImageLoader.ImageListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(ImageLoader.ImageContainer response, boolean isImmediate) {
                        Bitmap bm = response.getBitmap();
                        bm.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 70, null);

                        imageViewLoad.setImageBitmap(bm);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                    }
                });
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? To display a bitmap you need it in uncompressed format.

Comment: i was trying to do it in on response, actually when i try to display bitmap in my image it is taking few sec and i dont want this thats  why i wanted to compress the size of bitmap

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8417034/how-to-make-bitmap-compress-without-change-the-bitmap-size

Comment: try this method............    public String getStringImage(Bitmap bmp){
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
        byte[] imageBytes = baos.toByteArray();
        String encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(imageBytes, Base64.DEFAULT);
        return encodedImage;
    } and also check this tutorial https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/android-volley-tutorial-to-upload-image-to-server/

Comment: any thing i am doing in onrespose method bitmap is not displaying