# How to compress an image file in Android?

Tags: android, firebase, compression, firebase-storage, image-compression

So for each image I have its path (in the form of a string). And I convert that path string to a file. I then store that file into Firebase storage, but my problem is that the file is too large when I query. So I need to compress it before uploading it Firebase storage. I was looking around, but never found a clear cut solution on how to do this. Please if anyone can help me with very clear and simple solution that would be great. Below is my code.

```
for(String path : images)
{
    try {
    InputStream stream = new FileInputStream(new File(path));
    UploadTask uploadTask = imageStorage.putStream(stream);
    uploadTask.addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
            // Handle unsuccessful uploads
            Log.d("myStorage","failure :(");
        }
    }).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
            // taskSnapshot.getMetadata() contains file metadata such as size, content-type, and download URL.
            UrI downloadUrl = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl();
            Log.d("myStorage","success!");
        }
    });
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    }
    countDB++;

}
```

Comment: what format are you using to store image in db?. If possible, try to use BLOB format to store image. this will automatically reduce the image size to KB.

Comment: im using jpeg at the moment.

Comment: yes. but what is format in db? is it varchar or int or blob etc ?

Answer (score 2):

I have a custom class for Image Compression which I used for Firebase Storage, and the size was reduced significantly.

This class can be used to compress a Bitmap and also a File before sending to Firebase

```
public class ImageCompression {

public static Bitmap getThumbnail(Uri uri, Context context) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
    InputStream input = context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);

    BitmapFactory.Options onlyBoundsOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    onlyBoundsOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    onlyBoundsOptions.inDither = true;//optional
    onlyBoundsOptions.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;//optional
    BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input, null, onlyBoundsOptions);
    input.close();
    if ((onlyBoundsOptions.outWidth == -1) || (onlyBoundsOptions.outHeight == -1))
        return null;

    int originalSize = (onlyBoundsOptions.outHeight > onlyBoundsOptions.outWidth) ? onlyBoundsOptions.outHeight : onlyBoundsOptions.outWidth;

    double ratio = (originalSize > 500) ? (originalSize / 500) : 1.0;

    BitmapFactory.Options bitmapOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    bitmapOptions.inSampleSize = getPowerOfTwoForSampleRatio(ratio);
    bitmapOptions.inDither = true;//optional
    bitmapOptions.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;//optional
    input = context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input, null, bitmapOptions);
    input.close();
    return bitmap;
}

private static int getPowerOfTwoForSampleRatio(double ratio) {
    int k = Integer.highestOneBit((int) Math.floor(ratio));
    if (k == 0) return 1;
    else return k;
}

public static File compressFile(File file, Context context) {
    try {

        // BitmapFactory options to downsize the image
        BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        o.inSampleSize = 6;
        // factor of downsizing the image

        FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
        //Bitmap selectedBitmap = null;
        BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream, null, o);
        inputStream.close();

        // The new size we want to scale to
        final int REQUIRED_SIZE = 75;

        // Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
        int scale = 1;
        while (o.outWidth / scale / 2 >= REQUIRED_SIZE &&
                o.outHeight / scale / 2 >= REQUIRED_SIZE) {
            scale *= 2;
        }

        BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o2.inSampleSize = scale;
        inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);

        Bitmap selectedBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream, null, o2);
        inputStream.close();

        // here i override the original image file
        file.createNewFile();
        FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);

        selectedBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 50, outputStream);

        return file;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return null;
    }
}
} 



ImageCompression.compressFile(YourFile, this);
ImageCompression.getThumbnail(YourUri, this);
```

Comment: what would i put in replace of "MyApplication"

Comment: That's the context, I use the Application Context for this

Comment: in my case, if i made a context object and set that context object in a constructor, would that work as well? because I cannot access Application context the same way you do.

Comment: but the context class does not have. `.getInstance().getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri); ` So when i do `context.getInstance().getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);` it gives me a red line error

Comment: Theres still an error on `MyApplication` what do i replace that with?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128124/discussion-between-veeresh-charantimath-and-theq).

Comment: Amazing answer, thank you for the detailed solution!

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you have to do:

First, convert your image to bitmap:

```
Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) logo.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
```

In place of 'logo' put your imageView. Then,

```
byte[] byteImage = encodeToBase64(bitmap);

public static byte[] encodeToBase64(Bitmap image) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOS = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 25, byteArrayOS);
    byte[] byteArray = byteArrayOS.toByteArray();
    return byteArray;
}
```

You will store the image in bytes in 'byteImage' variable. The number '25' is how much percent you want to compress it. In this code, it's reducing the size of the image to 25%. Try the code and let me know :)

Comment: Yeah it was able to reduce the file size. If i want the image to be particularly 1024 x 1024, how would i do that?

Comment: You want to reduce the file size without reducing the resolution of the image?

Comment: @TheQ I don't know if this will work for you, but try using tinyPNG API, here is the link [TinyPNG](https://tinypng.com/developers)

Answer (score 0):

You can get required size bitmap using following code,

```
public static Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromArray(byte[] data, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
    final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length, options);
    options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth, reqHeight);
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    return BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length, options);
}

 public static int calculateInSampleSize(BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
    final int height = options.outHeight;
    final int width = options.outWidth;
    int inSampleSize = 1;
    if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {

        final int halfHeight = height / 2;
        final int halfWidth = width / 2;

        // Calculate the largest inSampleSize value that is a power of 2 and keeps both
        // height and width larger than the requested height and width.
        while ((halfHeight / inSampleSize) >= reqHeight
                && (halfWidth / inSampleSize) >= reqWidth) {
            inSampleSize *= 2;
        }
    }
    return inSampleSize;
}
```

call `decodeSampledBitmapFromArray` with byte array of bitmap & required width & height.

Following is the way you can get byte array from bitmap,

```
Bitmap bmp = Your_bitmap;
ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ImageView imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);
Bitmap bitmap = ImageUtils.getInstant().getCompressedBitmap("Your_Image_Path_Here");
imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

**ImageUtils.java:**

```
public class ImageUtils {

    public static ImageUtils mInstant;

    public static ImageUtils getInstant(){
        if(mInstant==null){
            mInstant = new ImageUtils();
        }
        return mInstant;
    }

    public  Bitmap getCompressedBitmap(String imagePath) {
        float maxHeight = 1920.0f;
        float maxWidth = 1080.0f;
        Bitmap scaledBitmap = null;
        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagePath, options);

        int actualHeight = options.outHeight;
        int actualWidth = options.outWidth;
        float imgRatio = (float) actualWidth / (float) actualHeight;
        float maxRatio = maxWidth / maxHeight;

        if (actualHeight > maxHeight || actualWidth > maxWidth) {
            if (imgRatio < maxRatio) {
                imgRatio = maxHeight / actualHeight;
                actualWidth = (int) (imgRatio * actualWidth);
                actualHeight = (int) maxHeight;
            } else if (imgRatio > maxRatio) {
                imgRatio = maxWidth / actualWidth;
                actualHeight = (int) (imgRatio * actualHeight);
                actualWidth = (int) maxWidth;
            } else {
                actualHeight = (int) maxHeight;
                actualWidth = (int) maxWidth;

            }
        }

        options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, actualWidth, actualHeight);
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
        options.inDither = false;
        options.inPurgeable = true;
        options.inInputShareable = true;
        options.inTempStorage = new byte[16 * 1024];

        try {
            bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagePath, options);
        } catch (OutOfMemoryError exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();

        }
        try {
            scaledBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(actualWidth, actualHeight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        } catch (OutOfMemoryError exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }

        float ratioX = actualWidth / (float) options.outWidth;
        float ratioY = actualHeight / (float) options.outHeight;
        float middleX = actualWidth / 2.0f;
        float middleY = actualHeight / 2.0f;

        Matrix scaleMatrix = new Matrix();
        scaleMatrix.setScale(ratioX, ratioY, middleX, middleY);

        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(scaledBitmap);
        canvas.setMatrix(scaleMatrix);
        canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, middleX - bmp.getWidth() / 2, middleY - bmp.getHeight() / 2, new Paint(Paint.FILTER_BITMAP_FLAG));

        ExifInterface exif = null;
        try {
            exif = new ExifInterface(imagePath);
            int orientation = exif.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, 0);
            Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
            if (orientation == 6) {
                matrix.postRotate(90);
            } else if (orientation == 3) {
                matrix.postRotate(180);
            } else if (orientation == 8) {
                matrix.postRotate(270);
            }
            scaledBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(scaledBitmap, 0, 0, scaledBitmap.getWidth(), scaledBitmap.getHeight(), matrix, true);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        scaledBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 85, out);

        byte[] byteArray = out.toByteArray();

        Bitmap updatedBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteArray, 0, byteArray.length);

        return updatedBitmap;
    }

    private int calculateInSampleSize(BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
        final int height = options.outHeight;
        final int width = options.outWidth;
        int inSampleSize = 1;

        if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {
            final int heightRatio = Math.round((float) height / (float) reqHeight);
            final int widthRatio = Math.round((float) width / (float) reqWidth);
            inSampleSize = heightRatio < widthRatio ? heightRatio : widthRatio;
        }
        final float totalPixels = width * height;
        final float totalReqPixelsCap = reqWidth * reqHeight * 2;

        while (totalPixels / (inSampleSize * inSampleSize) > totalReqPixelsCap) {
            inSampleSize++;
        }
        return inSampleSize;
    }
}
```

This will compress the size of image but didn't resize it.

Thanks to this answer [Compress bitmap in android](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36130103/3338287)