# How to reduce an Image file size

Tags: android, file

I use this function to reduce the size of image before uploading it,But using below method my file size is increasing

Before use below code my file size---> 157684

after using this code my file size ----->177435

Can some one help me please how can i reduce file size before upload to server

code:

```
public File saveBitmapToFile(File file){
    try {

        // BitmapFactory options to downsize the image
        BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        o.inSampleSize = 6;
        // factor of downsizing the image

        FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
        //Bitmap selectedBitmap = null;
        BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream, null, o);
        inputStream.close();

        // The new size we want to scale to
        final int REQUIRED_SIZE=75;

        // Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
        int scale = 1;
        while(o.outWidth / scale / 2 >= REQUIRED_SIZE &&
                        o.outHeight / scale / 2 >= REQUIRED_SIZE) {
            scale *= 2;
        }

        BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o2.inSampleSize = scale;
        inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);

        Bitmap selectedBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream, null, o2);
        inputStream.close();

        // here i override the original image file
        file.createNewFile();
        FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);

        selectedBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100 , outputStream);

        return file;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100 , outputStream to Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, REQUIRED_SIZE, outputStream

Comment: 100  is good quality     0 is bed quality .   so choose as per compression with quality ratio to reduce your file size

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8417034/how-to-make-bitmap-compress-without-change-the-bitmap-size

Comment: have you tried with PNG format instead?

Answer (score 1):

Change this line:

```
    selectedBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100 , outputStream);
```

to

```
int mCompressedSize = 50; // 0 is lowest and 100 original
selectedBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, mCompressedSize, outputStream);
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: REQUIRED_SIZE ? That 100 is a compress quality.

Answer (score 1):

This what I use to reduce my image size without compressing :

```
public static Bitmap getResizedBitmap(Bitmap bitmap, int newWidth, int newHeight) {
    Bitmap scaledBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(newWidth, newHeight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

    float ratioX = newWidth / (float) bitmap.getWidth();
    float ratioY = newHeight / (float) bitmap.getHeight();
    float middleX = newWidth / 2.0f;
    float middleY = newHeight / 2.0f;

    Matrix scaleMatrix = new Matrix();
    scaleMatrix.setScale(ratioX, ratioY, middleX, middleY);

    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(scaledBitmap);
    canvas.setMatrix(scaleMatrix);
    canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, middleX - bitmap.getWidth() / 2, middleY - bitmap.getHeight() / 2, new Paint(Paint.FILTER_BITMAP_FLAG));

    return scaledBitmap;
}
```

You just need to enter correct new height and width to fit your needs

Answer (score 1):

We want to make thumbnail of an image, so we need to first take the ByteArrayOutputStream and then pass it into Bitmap.compress() method.

```
ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
youBitmapImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, bytes);
```

more about the function, from the [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#compress(android.graphics.Bitmap.CompressFormat,%20int,%20java.io.OutputStream))

Answer (score 1):

If your output file is larger:

- it can mean that `scale` is wrong. And you save the file with 100% quality so it can grow
- compression on the input file is extremely heavy and even though you scale it, using no compression on the output still generates a larger file

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
int compressionRatio = 2; //1 == originalImage, 2 = 50% compression, 4=25% compress
File file = new File (imageUrl);
try {
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile (file.getPath ());
    bitmap.compress (Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, compressionRatio, new FileOutputStream (file));
}
catch (Throwable t) {
    Log.e("ERROR", "Error compressing file." + t.toString ());
    t.printStackTrace ();
}
```