# How to save a bitmap with same dimensions that of original?

Tags: android, image, bitmap, resize, save

I am writing a function, which takes a bitmap, edits it and saves it.
But the problem is that the saved image is not having the same dimensions.
Can anyone help me fix it? I want the output image to be of same length and width as that of the original image.

This is my code -

```
public void bitTest(View v) throws IOException {
    Drawable t=getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.slider_touch,getTheme());//the image to be processed
    Bitmap bit=((BitmapDrawable) t).getBitmap();//its bitmap
    Bitmap finalImage=Bitmap.createBitmap(bit.getWidth(),bit.getHeight(),bit.getConfig());//creating another bitmap of same dimensions

    Context context=getApplicationContext();
    FileOutputStream fos = context.openFileOutput("test.png", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);//saving
    finalImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG,100, fos);
    fos.close();

}
```

Here the original size is having dimensions of 288x192 but the output image has dimensions of 605x403.
Where am i wrong?

Also i have tried changing the quality, but it doesn't works.

Comment: What are the dimensions of Bitmap bit? They are already not equal to original isnt it?

Comment: @greenapps ohh i never thought abt it, let me check.

Comment: it's easily actually, just use google! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8417034/how-to-make-bitmap-compress-without-change-the-bitmap-size

Answer (score -1, accepted):

When placing the image resources in `drawable` directory, the decoded image size depends upon the screen size of the running device.

Keep your drawable inside the folder `drawable-nodpi` rather than other drawable directories so that the image size remains preserved.

Also rather than using `BitmapDrawable`, you can directly decode a bitmap from resource using `BitmapFactory.decodeResource()`

Comment: Please dont ask for that yourself. It makes a bad impression.