# How to fix android app crash issues?

Tags: java, android, xml

My project on android studio is running fine on few phones and emulators but crashes on many phones. I have a Main_Activity and clicking on login takes to a second activity. I am sharing the java files and xml files of both activities along with android manifest.

Main Activity Java file

```
package club.pithynews.iitbhilai_pithy;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private EditText username;
    private EditText password;
    private Button login_button;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        java.text.DateFormat dateFormat = android.text.format.DateFormat.getDateFormat(getApplicationContext());
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        LoginButton();
    }

    public void LoginButton() {
        username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
        password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        login_button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

        login_button.setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        if ((username.getText().toString().equals("user"))&&(password.getText().toString().equals("pass"))) {
                            Intent intent = new Intent("club.pithynews.iitbhilai_pithy.User");
                            startActivity(intent);
                        }
                    }
                }
        );
    }
}
```

Main Activity XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/back_login"
    tools:context="club.pithynews.iitbhilai_pithy.MainActivity">



    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:background="#11000000"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/user_name"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.78"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.53" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="#11000000"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/password"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.78"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.64" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"

        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:maxHeight="30dp"
        android:maxWidth="30dp"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.05"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.53"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/user1"
        android:contentDescription="@string/todo" />


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"

        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:maxHeight="30dp"
        android:maxWidth="30dp"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.06"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.64"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/lock1"
        android:contentDescription="@string/todo" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"

        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"

        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/back_login"
        android:text="@string/login"
        android:textSize="28sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.79" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView3"
        android:layout_width="233dp"
        android:layout_height="227dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="1dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"


        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.43"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.057"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/logoiit"
        android:contentDescription="@string/todo" />



</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout >
```

Second Activity Java file

```
package club.pithynews.iitbhilai_pithy;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class User extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_user);
    }
}
```

Second Activity XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/white"
    tools:context="club.pithynews.iitbhilai_pithy.User">

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton_emergency3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:maxWidth="80dp"
        android:maxHeight="100dp"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:layout_marginLeft="270dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="350dp"
        android:src="@drawable/emergency3"
        android:background="@null"
        android:layout_marginStart="270dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/todo13" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton_feedback1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:maxWidth="125dp"
        android:maxHeight="100dp"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:layout_marginLeft="265dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="445dp"
        android:src="@drawable/feedback1"
        android:background="@null"
        android:layout_marginStart="265dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/todo12" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton_aboutus1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:maxWidth="125dp"
        android:maxHeight="500dp"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:layout_marginLeft="125dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="455dp"
        android:src="@drawable/aboutus1"
        android:background="@null"
        android:layout_marginStart="125dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/todo11" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton_campusmap1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:maxWidth="125dp"
        android:maxHeight="80dp"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="455dp"
        android:src="@drawable/campusmap1"
        android:background="@null"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/todo10" />
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton_adminstrators"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:maxWidth="100dp"
        android:maxHeight="500dp"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:layout_marginLeft="140dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="350dp"
        android:src="@drawable/adminstrators"
        android:background="@null"
        android:layout_marginStart="140dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/todo9" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton_fnr"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="350dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:background="@null"
        android:contentDescription="@string/fee_and_registration"
        android:maxHeight="200dp"
        android:maxWidth="75dp"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:src="@drawable/fnr"

        android:layout_marginStart="25dp" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton_clubs"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="265dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="220dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:background="@null"
        android:maxHeight="500dp"
        android:maxWidth="100dp"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:src="@drawable/clubs"
        android:layout_marginStart="265dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/todo8" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton_studdata"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="135dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="220dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:background="@null"
        android:maxHeight="500dp"
        android:maxWidth="100dp"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:src="@drawable/studdata"
        android:layout_marginStart="135dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/todo7" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton_bus"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="220dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:background="@null"
        android:maxHeight="500dp"
        android:maxWidth="100dp"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:src="@drawable/bus"
        android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/todo6" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton_mess"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="265dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:background="@null"
        android:maxHeight="500dp"
        android:maxWidth="100dp"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:src="@drawable/mess"
        android:layout_marginStart="265dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/todo5" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton_faculty"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="135dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:background="@null"
        android:maxHeight="500dp"
        android:maxWidth="100dp"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:src="@drawable/faculty"
        android:layout_marginStart="135dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/todo4" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton_academics"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:background="@null"
        android:maxHeight="500dp"
        android:maxWidth="100dp"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:src="@drawable/academics"
        android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/todo3" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton_newsletter"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="265dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:background="@null"
        android:maxHeight="500dp"
        android:maxWidth="100dp"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:src="@drawable/news"
        android:layout_marginStart="265dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/todo" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton_events"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="135dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:background="@null"
        android:maxHeight="500dp"
        android:maxWidth="100dp"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:src="@drawable/events"
        android:layout_marginStart="135dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/todo1" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton_today"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:background="@null"
        android:maxHeight="500dp"
        android:maxWidth="100dp"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:src="@drawable/today"
        android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/todo2" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/imageButton_emergency3"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/imageButton_emergency3"
        android:text="@string/textview5"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:visibility="visible"
        tools:text="   Emergency  " />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/imageButton_adminstrators"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/imageButton_adminstrators"
        android:text="@string/administrators"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageButton_bus"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/imageButton_bus"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageButton_fnr"
        android:text="@string/textview4"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        tools:text=" Fees and\n Registration" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageButton_campusmap1"
        android:text="@string/textview3"
        tools:text=" Campus Map"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageButton_adminstrators"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/imageButton_adminstrators"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageButton_campusmap1"
        android:text="@string/textview2"
        tools:text="      About Us"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageButton_feedback1"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/imageButton_feedback1"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView5"
        android:text="@string/textview1"
        tools:text="     Feedback"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Android Manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="club.pithynews.iitbhilai_pithy">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".User">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="club.pithynews.iitbhilai_pithy.User" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>

</resources>
```

Debug Report when app crashes

```
W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/club.pithynews.iitbhilai_pithy-1/lib/arm
I/InstantRun: starting instant run server: is main process
W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
D/TextView: setTypeface with style : 0
D/TextView: setTypeface with style : 0
W/ResourceType: Failure getting entry for 0x7f06005a (t=5 e=90) (error -75)
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: club.pithynews.iitbhilai_pithy, PID: 16468
                  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{club.pithynews.iitbhilai_pithy/club.pithynews.iitbhilai_pithy.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
                   Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:551)
                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120) 
                   Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
                      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6904) 
                      at a
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7331) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120) 
                   Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource "club.pithynews.iitbhilai_pithy:drawable/back_login" (7f06005a) is not a Drawable (color or path): TypedValue{t=0x1/d=0x7f06005a a=-1 r=0x7f06005a}
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7331) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

Comment: Can you share error log?

Comment: what's the error? Please share logcat/stacktrace!

Comment: Try to put         `java.text.DateFormat dateFormat = android.text.format.DateFormat.getDateFormat(getApplicationContext());`
 below of setContentView

Comment: 111300000 bytes ~ 100 MB worth of image?

Comment: I have not used any image of 100 mb. All images are light. Even after removing all the image views and buttons, the problem persists. Meanwhile I have updated the debug report.

Answer (score 1):

Error is self explanatory. You're trying to load an image that is too big.

```
Canvas: trying to draw too large(111300000bytes) bitmap.
```

One of your drawable source that you set on your `ImageButton` or `ImageView` is too big. You can:

- Scale image manually
- Perform scaling in code and set the image afterwards

Answer (score 0):

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Canvas: trying to draw too large(111300000bytes) bitmap.
```

As you can see, you are trying to display an image that is too large. Check the size of the included bitmap resources.

Answer (score 0):

you are displaying an image of size *111.3 mb* which is too large to handle you need to compress and scale to some smaller version before displaying.
here you can scale your image.

```
Bitmap scaled = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(originalBitmap, 120, 120, false);
```

more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4837715/how-to-resize-a-bitmap-in-android)
and compress using

```
ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
scaledBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 85, out);
```

see more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8417034/how-to-make-bitmap-compress-without-change-the-bitmap-size)