# After Uploading photo on server from android Application, it lost his quality

Tags: android

While I select the image from the gallery and shows it in ImageView. The image quality is all right. But, uploading an image on the server, it lost quality and become a blur. I obtain the image from the camera by this code.

```java
private void onCaptureImageResult(Intent data) {
    bitmap = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
    ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);

    File destination = new File(
        Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
        System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg"
    );

    FileOutputStream fo;
    try {
        destination.createNewFile();
        fo = new FileOutputStream(destination);
        fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());
        fo.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
}
```

Then, I did this work-

```java
private String imageToString(Bitmap bitmap){
    ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream=new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,100,byteArrayOutputStream);
    byte[] imgByte=byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
    return Base64.encodeToString(imgByte,Base64.DEFAULT);
}
```

and used this function to compress my selected photo. But, it makes the loss of that image quality and image become a blur on the server. Why am I facing this problem?

Comment: Most likely, the input `Bitmap` has already reduced quality. How did you obtain it?

Comment: is there any way to upload image on server with it's perfect quality?

Comment: Yes there is. What I am saying is the problem is not in the code you have shown.

Comment: I edited the post with code. Check it

Comment: Where does the `Intent data` come from? For example if it is the result delivered from the camera then the bitmap is just a very small preview image.

Comment: See, [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `.png` format as it's lossless and doesn't reduce the image quality. On the other hand the `.jpeg` format is just the opposite of this.

```java
private String imageToString(Bitmap bitmap){
    ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream=new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, byteArrayOutputStream);
    byte[] imgByte=byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
    return Base64.encodeToString(imgByte, Base64.DEFAULT);
}
```

Comment: Well, JPEG compression with quality 100 does not lead to a noticeable loss of quality.

Comment: @Henry Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8417034/how-to-make-bitmap-compress-without-change-the-bitmap-size)

Comment: @Henry Ok. I'll do it

Answer (score 0):

You did not show the intent to start a Camera app.

But you did it in such a way that you only got a thumbnail of the picture taken.

Change the intent. Add an uri where the camera app can save the full picture.

There are 783 examples of such an intent on stackoverflow and even more on the internet.