# Download image and resize to avoid OOM errors, Picasso fit() distorts image

Tags: android-image, picasso

I am trying to show images in a full screen view and using the following code:

```
// Target to write the image to local storage.
Target target = new Target() {
   // Target implementation.
}

// (1) Download and save the image locally.
Picasso.with(context)
       .load(url)
       .into(target);

// (2) Use the cached version of the image and load the ImageView.
Picasso.with(context)
       .load(url)
       .into(imgDisplay);
```

This code works well on newer phones, but on phones with 32MB VMs, I get out of memory issues. So I tried changing (2) to:

```
    Picasso.with(context)
       .load(url)
       .fit()
       .into(imgDisplay);
```

This resulted in distorted images. Since I do not know the dimensions of the image until it is downloaded, I cannot set the ImageView dimensions, and hence the image is being resized without any consideration to aspect ratio in to my ImageView:

```
    <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imgDisplay"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
```

What is the best way to handle this situation? My original images have max width 768, and height 1024, and I want to downsample when the screens are much smaller than this. If I try to use `resize()`, my code becomes complicated, as I have to wait for (1) to finish the download and then add the `resize()` in (2).

I am assuming Transformations do not help in this case, as the input to `public Bitmap transform(Bitmap source)` will already have the large bitmap which will cause me to run out of memory.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can combine `fit()` with `centerCrop()` or `centerInside()`, depending on how you want the image to fit your `View`:

```
Picasso.with(context)
   .load(url)
   .fit()
   .centerCrop()
   .into(imgDisplay);

Picasso.with(context)
   .load(url)
   .fit()
   .centerInside()
   .into(imgDisplay);
```

Comment: This works! I was thrown off by the documentation which caused me to think `centerInside()` needs to be used with `resize()`

[From Doc](https://square.github.io/picasso/javadoc/com/squareup/picasso/RequestCreator.html#centerInside--): `Centers an image inside of the bounds specified by resize(int, int). This scales the image so that both dimensions are equal to or less than the requested bounds.`

Comment: I know, it's a common mistake and the docs are not crystal clear about it. FYI, `fit()` just waits for the View to get its dimensions, but does actually nothing to **scale** the image to that size

Comment: [fit()](https://square.github.io/picasso/javadoc/com/squareup/picasso/RequestCreator.html#fit--) says `Attempt to resize the image to fit exactly into the target ImageView's bounds.` So is it not scaling the bitmap? I am a bit confused by your last comment. I want to make sure downsampling is done and I load the correctly sized bitmap to avoid wasting memory. What is the best way to do this? BTW, I have another `View` in my app that has a fixed NxN dimension where I used `fit()` along with `centerCrop()` assuming downsampling will happen.

Comment: Yes, it does downsample the original image by using the `View` size. But what about the aspect ratio? Picasso does not know what to do if you have a square-shaped `View` and a rect-shaped image. That's why you need to combine `fit()` with one of the other two. Is it clearer now?

Comment: Yep, got it! Picasso will do the correct downsampling to fit the `View` and adjust for aspect ratio when `fit()` is used along with `centerInside()`. `centerCrop()` can be used to make sure the image fills the full `View` and in the case of a rectangular image being put in a square `View`, it will crop the image.