# Compress a 1080p video pngs into small size

Tags: android, bitmap

I am developing an app which generate .png images from a 1080p video. But the pngs are in MBs, and even my app is crashing due to large size of pngs. I want to compress or something like that to reduce the size of each png. I have done a lot of methods like `createScaledBitmap`, or `compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 20, stream);` or `Bitmap.createBitmap(source, 0, 0, source.getWidth(),source.getHeight(), m, true);` also searched a lot of methods.
But it's not reducing the size as much as I want. it still remains in 2.2+ MB per png.
Any idea other than these. Thanks.

Comment: I am also building a app which deals with High resolution images. But on server side I am compressing and re-size the image on server side by using "thumbnailator-0.4.8.jar".

Comment: You will find info on this question/answer helpful. http://stackoverflow.com/a/10652312/940834

Comment: A Bitmap uses a lot of memory. If the PNG is 2.2+MB, you can assume the Bitmap is going to be even larger. You need to compress to a lossy image format (JPEG), or reduce the size/quality of the PNG. You're probably better off converting to JPG.

Comment: Try using `compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 50, stream);`

Comment: @Der Golem, Sir i am bounded to use only .png images, i can't use jpeg images

Comment: @Eugene K , i already tried this method, but its not working, and i need only png images not jpeg. So, even i set to compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 0, stream); but its still give me about 2Mb of bitmap, secondly i also used createBitmap method to resize or crop the image but its not working or the image intensity is much higher that my app still crashing..

Answer (score 0):

I am also building an app which deals with high resolution images but on server side. I am compressing and re-sizing the image on server side by using [thumbnailator-0.4.8.jar](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.coobird/thumbnailator/0.4.8). Example

```
InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);
BufferedImage bImageFromConvert = ImageIO.read( in );
BufferedImage newImage = Thumbnails.of(bImageFromConvert).size(213, 316).asBufferedImage();
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
ImageIO.write(newImage, "jpg", baos);
baos.flush();
retVal = baos.toByteArray();
baos.close();
```

Comment: @Marco Sorry for late reply i will try this source.