# PlayN Android 2.3.x OutOfMemory

Tags: android, playn

In our app we have a lot of images. When they needed we get them in 
such way: `PlayN.assets().getImage("imageURL");`

In android 2.3 there is limit for 24mb of bitmap resources. So, while 
showing images on Screen2(let's say Game)  i must hide (unload) images 
from Screen1(lets say Intro). 
I have reference to image from Screen1 and i can call clear() method: 
CanvaseImage referenceToImage - i need to unload, 
`referenceToImage.canvas().clear();`

BUT, - this way do not unload image from android memory in 2.3.x - 
( [Android: Bitmap recycle() how does it work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3823799/android-bitmap-recycle-how)... 
this post tell that i should call recycle() on bitmap, since bitmaps 
are stored in non-management memory and cant be shrinked from there by 
GC.)

and i have such stackTrace for android if images from Screen1 are not 
unloaded from memory:

```
06-11 09:16:45.197: E/AndroidRuntime(23621): FATAL EXCEPTION: GLThread 
10 
06-11 09:16:45.197: E/AndroidRuntime(23621): 
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget(Heap 
Size=9479KB, Allocated=6032KB, Bitmap Size=23347KB) 
06-11 09:16:45.197: E/AndroidRuntime(23621):    at 
android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeStream(Native Method) 
06-11 09:16:45.197: E/AndroidRuntime(23621):    at 
android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:694) 
06-11 09:16:45.197: E/AndroidRuntime(23621):    at 
playn.android.AndroidAssets.decodeBitmap(AndroidAssets.java:158) 
06-11 09:16:45.197: E/AndroidRuntime(23621):    at 
playn.android.AndroidAssets.doGetImage(AndroidAssets.java:79) 
06-11 09:16:45.197: E/AndroidRuntime(23621):    at 
playn.core.AbstractAssets.getImage(AbstractAssets.java:39)
```

Is there some way to call playN 's magic for recycling bitmaps in 
Android 2.3.x memory model?

Answer (score 1):

Have you already taken a look at the [Google article](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html) about memory managment?  They really give a fairly in depth explanation of how to deal with that bitmap issue.

Answer (score 1):

why don't you use [LruCache](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/LruCache.html) for caching bitmaps? see article [here](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/cache-bitmap.html)