# OutOfMemory decoding image with inJustDecodeBounds=true

Tags: java, android, image, android-camera, out-of-memory

I continuously get OutOfMemory exceptions trying to decode an image from camera in my Android app. There are many questions dealing with the problem, but my case is especially weird because I get the exception even when just trying to get the bounds with `options.inJustDecodeBounds=true`.

Here's the code that starts the camera:

```
protected void takePicture() {
    Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    File image = new File(IMAGE_PATH, "camera.jpg");
    takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(image));
    startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, 0);
}
```

Here's the code that triggers the exception:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK ) { 
        String rawImageName = new String(IMAGE_PATH + "/camera.jpg");

        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeFile(rawImageName); // The exception is thrown here
            .
            .
            .
    }
}
```

I tried to decode the image using a very high sampling rate, but still I get the same exception:

```
options.inSampleSize = 20;
options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.RGB_565;
Bitmap photo = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(rawImageName); // Again the exception
```

Except for that, the application seems to run correctly and there is enough free memory. I can open correctly the image in the gallery app. Moving the image to a different directory didn't help. Any ideas what could cause it? What could possibly cause the exception while decoding with `inJustDecodeBounds = true`?

Comment: show us your stacktrace.

Comment: i think you should take a look at this link : http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html

Comment: Well, it happens to be a stupid copy-paste error. Should the question be deleted? Does it have any value for others?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to pass the options to the decode call:

```
BitmapFactory.decodeFile(rawImageName, options);
```

Comment: Oh, my stupidity!!! That's what happens when you copy-paste your code. Grrr hours of pulling my hair out!!!

Answer (score 2):

```
BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
o2.inSampleSize = 4; // 1/4
o2.inPurgeable = true;
Bitmap b=BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagePath,o2);
```

try this. and also resize your image and make bitmap objects null after use.
give call to `System.gc();` it doesn call gc but it gives hint.
also dont make lots of bitmap objects. reuse the same bitmap object and make it null after use.

Comment: Rather use recycle() on the bitmap instead of gc. GC might not free up the memory immediately. See http://mobi-solutions.blogspot.com/2010/08/how-to-if-you-want-to-create-and.html and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3823799/android-bitmap-recycle-how-does-it-work

Comment: Yes you are right. If you are no more using bitmap objects recycle them.

Comment: Calling System.gc() is really an anti-pattern that should be avoided. You can find a lot of documentation about this online. To summarize, it screams "broken code", it's not guaranteed to do anything and it might slow your code down, because you might start a full GC cycle. Always avoid System.gc().