# Android: Out of memory after creating and skewing Bitmap from Drawing Cache

Tags: android, bitmap, out-of-memory

My approach is the following:

I have three `TextViews` (nested in a `LinearLayout`) and I want them to have a skewing effect, so that it looks like they are at a wall (look at the image below). Since the user can change the background (different wall), I am using the `DrawingCache` from the `LinearLayout`, skew it, and finally render it in a transparent image which is placed above the background image..

[image]

To ensure that the text is at the right position at every device, I came up with the solution to have a background image (720x1022) and render the text to a transparent image and place it at the right coordinates in a graphic with the same size (720x1022). In the app, pictures are scaled and placed the same way. Maybe it's not the best idea, because sometimes (let's say 1 time out of 10) I am running into an OutOfMemory Error.

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
at android.graphics.Bitmap.nativeCreate(Native Method)
at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:689)
at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:666)
at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:633)
//or

java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:502)
at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:355)
at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:785)
at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1965)
at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:601)
```

and the heap is growing suddenly.

```
  Grow heap (frag case) to 73.520MB for 11773456-byte allocation
```

It doesn't crash every time (let's say 1 out of 10), and not at the same position. Here's my implementation:

First, we get the user input from the TextViews which are nested in a LinearLayout and scale it to a specific height and width (#2) to perform the skewing matrix (#3).

```
//#1 get Text from TextViews
View test = findViewById(R.id.signFakeContainer);
test.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
Bitmap mOfferText = test.getDrawingCache();

//#2 scale Text to specific width & height to perform skew effect
Bitmap mScaledBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(mOfferText, 560, 720, false);

int mTextViewWidth = mScaledBitmap.getWidth();
int mTextViewHeight = mScaledBitmap.getHeight();

//#3 create skewing matrix
Matrix mMatrix2 = new Matrix();
float[] mStartSrc = new float[] { 0, 0, mTextViewWidth, 0, mTextViewWidth, mTextViewHeight, 0, mTextViewHeight };
float[] mDestSrc = new float[] { 0, 4f, 520f, 0f, 552f, 704f, 22f, 720f };
mMatrix2.setPolyToPoly(mStartSrc, 0, mDestSrc, 0, 4);

//#4 perform skewing
Bitmap mStrechtedTextView = Bitmap.createBitmap(mScaledBitmap, 0, 0, mTextViewWidth, mTextViewHeight, mMatrix2, false);

//#5 place 560x720 image in 720x1022 image at specific coordinates, to ensure its right position 
Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.transparent_dummy), 720, 1022, false);
Canvas comboImage = new Canvas(bmp);
comboImage.drawBitmap(mStrechtedTextView, 98, 110, null);

//#6 set rendered textview to image
ImageView mOfferImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.choose_sign_offer_image);
mOfferImageView.setImageBitmap(bmp);
```

I found this really good article: [Strange out of memory issue while loading an image to a Bitmap object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/477572/strange-out-of-memory-issue-while-loading-an-image-to-a-bitmap-object) but still it doesn't solve my issue. I guess I still have too many `createBitmaps`. Maybe there's a better way to do this, so I'm happy for every suggestion!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Our final solution for this case, was the use of an `AsyncTask` for rendering the `Image`. We pass a reference to the `LinearLayout` which included the `TextViews` (this is what we are rendering), a reference for the `ImageView` where we insert the rendered picture and a reference to `ProgressBar` which is hided after the Image is rendered

```
public class RenderBitmapWorkerTask extends AsyncTask<Integer, Void, Bitmap> {
  private final WeakReference<ImageView> imageViewReference;
  private final LinearLayout signViewReference;
  private final ProgressBar progressBar;

  public RenderBitmapWorkerTask(ImageView imageView, LinearLayout signView, ProgressBar mProgressBar) {
      // Use a WeakReference to ensure the ImageView can be garbage collected
      imageViewReference = new WeakReference<ImageView>(imageView);
      signViewReference = signView;
      progressBar = mProgressBar;
  }

  // Decode image in background.
  @Override
  protected Bitmap doInBackground(Integer... params) {
    signViewReference.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);

    Bitmap mOfferText = signViewReference.getDrawingCache();

    int mTextViewWidth = 560;
        int mTextViewHeight = 720;

        mOfferText = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(mOfferText, mTextViewWidth, mTextViewHeight, false);

        Matrix mMatrix2 = new Matrix();
        float[] mStartSrc = new float[] { 0, 0, mTextViewWidth, 0, mTextViewWidth, mTextViewHeight, 0, mTextViewHeight };
        float[] mDestSrc = new float[] { 0, 4f, 520f, 0f, 552f, 704f, 22f, 720f };
        mMatrix2.setPolyToPoly(mStartSrc, 0, mDestSrc, 0, 4);
        mOfferText = Bitmap.createBitmap(mOfferText, 0, 0, mTextViewWidth, mTextViewHeight, mMatrix2, false);

      return mOfferText;
  }

  // Once complete, see if ImageView is still around and set bitmap.
  @Override
  protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
      if (imageViewReference != null && bitmap != null) {
          final ImageView imageView = imageViewReference.get();
          if (imageView != null) {

                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

              imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
          }
      }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I see at least 4 `Bitmap`s in de code snippet you posted. Make sure to read about proper bitmap recycling at [this android developer training link](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html) or [on this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3823799/android-bitmap-recycle-how-does-it-work).

#### Recycle

When adding [`recycle()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#recycle%28%29) calls make sure not to display a recycled bitmap or you'll get another error. Before assigning new bitmap information perform a recycle (if not `null`) and `onDestroy` of the view (or `onPause` if you're careful enough to recreate the bitmap `onResume`)

A quick example:

```
// you see how I moved this up to class scope instead?
private Bitmap mScaledBitmap = null;

void someMethod(){
    // some code here
    // ...
    if(mScaledBitmap != null)
        mScaledBitmap.recycle();
    mScaledBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(mOfferText, 560, 720, false);
    // more code here
    // ...
}

public void onDestroy(){
    // always call super
    super.onDestroy();
    // free memory from bitmap here
    if( mScaledBitmap != null ) {
        mScaledBitmap.recycle();
        mScaledBitmap = null;
    }
}
```

#### sampleSize

If even with proper recycling this code still gives out of memory exceptions you can try using the [sampleSize](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.Options.html#inSampleSize) options. Make sure to use powers of 2 then.

Another quick example for this:

```
Options opts = new Options();
opts.inSampleSize = 4;
// insert recycle here with proper checks
mScaledBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagePath, opts);
```

Comment: thanks for comment (whoever gave you a downvote?!), it doesn't really fit my needs, since you cannot give the 'Options' to 'Bitmap.createScaledBitmap'. I realized, that the 'createBitmap's are the critical ones, but I don't see any optimizing in the createImage -> scale -> skew -> render ... But maybe the whole idea of how to create that effect is stupid?!